# Linux server's disk full

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, disk-space-utilization

I use WinSCP to upload my website's pages to a remote Ubuntu Linux server (VPS xen hosting).
When I copy a file, it is written in the server with size=0.
When I checked the free disk space:
`df -h`
I got:
/dev/xvda with Avail=0% and Used=100%
I tried to check for deleted files with:
`lsof | grep '(deleted)'`
But the lsof command is not found.
What can I do next?

Comment: Do you have the privileges to install `lsof`?

Comment: Yes, but there is no disk space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried: sudo du -h --max-depth=1 ./ And iterating down the tree,
>   found that /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log has size of 13G!!!! I
>   deleted access.log with rm access.log. But df -h steel reports
>   /dev/xvda 0% avail... Should I do anything else to finally delete the
>   file?????

Now lsof should report deleted file. You should send HUP signal to http server using

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

In the future avoid this by editing /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 (enter correct path for your logs)

Comment: Is there a way to limit the size of access.log file, so I can avoid this mess?

Comment: As I mentioned look at logrotate file. It will hold only logs for the last XX days (rotate XX). Moreover logs older than 2 days will be archived.

Answer (score 0):

The lsof command looks like it only lists files that are about to be deleted (because they are in use). Maybe lsof exists but is not in your path - try searching for it.

You could:

- delete files you don't need: try looking for large directores or files - see the command 'du'.
- ask for more space from the provider

Comment: I tried:

    sudo du -h --max-depth=1 ./

And iterating down the tree, found that /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log has size of 13G!!!!
I deleted access.log with rm access.log.
But df -h steel reports /dev/xvda 0% avail...
Should I do anything else to finally delete the file?????

Answer (score 0):

/dev/xvda is a disc path. Partitions should end with some number (ex. /dev/xvda1). Check in df in the last column if it is your root or home partition. "Avail=0%" tells you probably run out of free space. Check what is taking to much space using

```
du -sm <path>
```

For your home directory it would be

```
du -sm $HOME/*
```

Comment: /dev/xvda is mounted on /

Comment: sudo du -sm / results with: cannot access '/proc/22858...' errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to find out what file or directory is using most of disk space

`du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10`

The command work in the directory where you will start it. It shows 10 biggest files/directorys.

Use it on directory that you have suspicion that files in there are to big ie /var/log/ your home directory.

If you find nothing then something maybe wrong with your hdd.

UPDATE:
If you have perl installed you can use this one liner:

`du -k | sort -n | perl -ne 'if ( /^(\d+)\s+(.*$)/){$l=log($1+.1);$m=int($l/log(1024)); printf  ("%6.1f\t%s\t%25s  %s\n",($1/(2**(10*$m))),(("K","M","G","T","P")[$m]),"*"x (1.5*$l),$2);}'`